# Math question help here? Tangents

Tags: derivatives

Find $a$, $b$ and $c$ so the line $y=x$ can be a tangent of the parabola $y=ax^2+ bx+c$ at the point $x=1$. The parabola passes from the point $M(-1;0)$. So I formed the system $$2a+b=1$$ $$a-b+c=0$$
How do I solve this system?

Details : From $y=x$ we see that $k=1$ (we also have that $x=1$) so $2\cdot a\cdot 1+b\cdot 1=1$

Comment: @froggie: Is my answer below wrong? :(

Comment: Wasn't my answer good? :)

Answer (score 1):

The parabola and the line intersect each other at $x=1$. This gives you another equation.

Comment: Right! I missed that,thanks :)

Comment: + Hi, Babak! Hope to see you soon! ;-)